# detect end of song - SoundJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, soundjs

I am using [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/soundjs) to play music. How can I detect when a song has ended?

SoundJS can detect events, is there an event for when a song ends? something like this:

```
var songInstance = createjs.Sound.play("sound");
songInstance.on("_SONG_ENDED_", function(){
     //do something after song has ended
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do the below code based off this site: http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/Sound.html

```
instance.on("complete", this.handleComplete, this);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I tried that; I believe "complete" means "completed loading the song" rather than "completed listening to the song"

Comment: Makes sense, sorry I don't have much else.

Comment: This answer is correct. The "complete" event on the instance signifies that the sound has completed playback. There is a similar "complete" event in PreloadJS for audio loading, but the internal preloading of a Sound in SoundJS is a "fileload" event. Here is the docs on the instance "complete" event. http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/AbstractSoundInstance.html#event_complete